# Set codebehind public property directly from ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have three usercontrols: `usercontrolA`, `usercontrolB` and `usercontrolC` which *all share the same codebehind* each having:

`<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="True" Codebehind="usercontrolA.ascx.cs" Inherits="usercontrolA" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>` at the top of the ascx.

In the codebehind file I have a public property called `ShowAll`.

I know I can set this property when I put the usercontrol on the page e.g.

`<uc1:usercontrolB ID="usercontrolB1" runat="server" ShowAll="true" />`

However *I would like ShowAll to always be set to true on usercontrolB* so would rather not have to set it every time it is placed on a page.

I know I can add a script tag to usercontrolB to set ShowAll in `Page_Load`:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowAll = true;
    }
</script>
```

But want to keep the `Page_Load` implementation I already have in the codebehind.  **Is there any other way to set this property automatically for usercontrolB?**

**Edit:** If it's possible I'd like to be able to set this in the ascx rather than in the code behind, so that someone else later on could add `usercontrolD` and set `ShowAll` to true for all instances of `usercontrolD` without needing to get me to modify and recompile the codebehind.

Comment: why do you have to share code-behind?

Comment: @Arief, that's one of the main principles of object-oriented programming.

Comment: @Arief to avoid duplicating a lot of code for what is essentially the same control with variations in html markup

Comment: I mean if you would have different behavior, why do you share the same code in the first place? Can't you use inheritance? cc @Kon

Comment: The type of problems you're having should raise a flag. Perhaps it's time to back up and refactor your design. It really looks like this is a candidate for inheritance rather than outright code sharing.

Comment: I'll have a look at doing that - thanks Arief and Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set this in usercontrol class constructor.

```
public ConstructorClassName()
    {
       ShowAll = true;
    }
```

here is complete example with code...

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  public WebUserControl()
  {
    ShowAll = true;
  }
  private bool _showAll;
  public bool ShowAll
  {
    get { return _showAll; }
    set { _showAll = value; }
  }   

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }
}
```

I set the default value to true, but you can also pass the value where you add this user control. e.g.

```
<uc1:usercontrolB ID="usercontrolB1" runat="server" ShowAll="false" />
```

When this is called, it will overwrite the value to `false`

Comment: Given that all three share the same code behind, how can I set the property just for usercontrolB?

Comment: Sure - but the question was is there any way to do this without having to do this every time the usercontrol gets put on a page?  The answer may well be that it's not possible!

Comment: Can you please explain more, I am not getting you. What actually you want?

Comment: Is there any way of setting a codebehind property from the ascx page itself e.g. perhaps in a script tag like in my example (but without hiding the codebehind's page_load)?

Comment: that's what set from aspx page <uc1:usercontrolB ID="usercontrolB1" runat="server" ShowAll="false" />, it will set code behind to true. can you test?

Comment: I agree - that does work, but we'll need to do that every time anyone puts it on a page.  Which is what I was hoping to avoid - I was hoping I could set this by default for all instances of usercontrolB.  I'm assuming what I want is not possible then.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you can check the instance type:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this is usercontrolB) 
    {
         ShowAll = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But as they share the same codebehind, I don't have a usercontrolB class, so surely I can't check if (this is usercontrolB) ?

Comment: Based on your sample code:  `<uc1:usercontrolB .../>`, you have a usercontrolB class defined.  `(this is usercontrolB)` is checking against the type, not the name of the user control.

Comment: Yes - I don't have a usercontrolB class defined though I just have `<%@ Register src="usercontrols/usercontrolB.ascx" tagname="usercontrolB" tagprefix="uc1" %>` at the top of my aspx page which allows me to reference the usercontrol as I have. I have three usercontrols which all have `usercontrolA.ascx.cs` for their codebehind and which all inherit `usercontrolA`