# ASP.NET ASCX file returns false for IsMobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile

Using old school webforms, I am testing the value of Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice  in both an ASPX and and ASCX file.  The ASPX file returns true but the ASCX file returns false.  I am using Chrome to test.  How do I get round the discrepancy?

Can I have a global variable set in the ASPX code which is called first and have the ASCX access it?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why ascx returns false maybe you need to call the full namespace , but simply you can pass IsMobileRequest as parameter to ascx.

please refer to this examples :

[Pass a value from aspx to ascx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657491/pass-a-value-from-aspx-to-ascx)

[Set codebehind public property directly from ascx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829928/set-codebehind-public-property-directly-from-ascx)